# Using Firebase in Node Server Typescript File

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, firebase, webpack

• I recently implemented server side rendering using Angular Universal in my application.

• This required converting my node server file from .js to .ts.

• Typescript is compiled to javascript using webpack

• Everything works when I run the server using : ts-node server.ts

• After compiling to javascript using webpack, I get the following error for Firebase API's used in my server:

ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auto-auth/node_modules/mime/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './types/standard' in '/Users/XX/Desktop/XX/XX/node_modules/google-auto-auth/node_modules/mime'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/mime/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './types/standard' in '/Users/XX/Desktop/XX/OM-XX/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/mime'

etc. etc.

How can this be tackled?

My webpack config code:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {server: './server.ts'},
  resolve: {extensions: ['.js', '.ts']},
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'none',
  // this makes sure we include node_modules and other 3rd party libraries
  externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader'}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // Temporary Fix for issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
    // for "WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression"
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: i am also trying same thing. did you got any solution @Mazlan Alam Malik??? Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be related to missing types?

Try to install missing typesfor all the packages that throw error

e.g: `npm install --save @types/google-cloud__storage`

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and still didn’t work. Thank you for the suggestion.